# Cura Filling holes from a model from Blender

Tags: ultimaker-cura, anycubic-i3-mega, blender

I am Attempting to print this, from Blender
[image]
But Cura decides to fill in the middle part of the model. 
[image]
I exported and imported the model from an STL file.

If anyone can answer this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Likely the STL file is not actually valid (doesn't make up a manifold). I'm not sure if getting bad STL files like that is a common issue that can happen with Blender; it happens with various low-quality tools.

Comment: :D there are faces inside the infill area.

Comment: Have you tried to heal your model in Meshlab, then save and import into Cura?

Comment: Nope, I've never tried Meshlab, never even heard of it until now.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling the "Union Overlapping Volumes" option on Mesh Fixes section. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an actual CAD/CAM program, such as Autodesk Fusion 360, instead of using a 3d model program. Not only will this be able to directly export you finished model to Cura, and the models are made in a way that works with a 3d printing slicer, there will be more help around 3D printing for it.

Although it is slightly difficult to use to start with, as you become more proficient, it is a very powerful tool to have. . Fusion 360 is free for hobbyists or students. See this link for help activating: https://www.autodesk.com/campaigns/fusion-360-for-hobbyists.

Another option would be SolidWorks, although you do have to pay for this option, but it is much simpler to work with in my opinion.

Comment: SolidWorks is so extremely expensive -- $4000+ USD -- that "you have to pay" does not really describe it.

Comment: Other free option that are easier to use for beginners: Design Spark Mechanical. Not as powerful though.

Comment: @Trish Thanks for suggesting that. I will edit my post and add it.

Comment: I've never had problems with models from FreeCAD, OpenSCAD, or QCAD, either.

Comment: @Davo I'll edit my answer later to include these suggestions. I first need to try them though just to make sure there are no problems, or if there is anything confusing about it. Thanks.